# OPOS receipt printer data sniffer / analyzer

Tags: visual-c++, usb, opos, thermal-printer, receipt

I am adding some functionality to an application that prints to a USB connected OPOS receipt printer. The system runs xp.

I want to see the raw data that gets passed to the receipt printer as well as have the printer physically print.

Is there any way I can do that? I looked some port monitors such as [Advanced USB Port Monitor](http://www.aggsoft.com/usb-port-monitor.htm) but they only detect and monitor devices that are accessible by native Operating System and not OPOS devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the "debug" version of the OPOS common controls, instead of the "runtime" version.  They will emit trace information you're looking for.
http://www.monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm

Be careful not to deploy the debug version in your production environment, as you might violate some requirements for data security.

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting the print queue to keep printed documents and use a hex editor, such as notepad++ with the hexeditor plug-in? (marked as unstable but it works fine. Other hex editors are available). It takes a while for your eye to adjust to the code but it's just like reading the matrix after a while.